# Integral with sum of differentials

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Somebody can help telling what this integral means?

$$\int (x+y) dx+dy$$

On the path $g(t)=(t,t^2)$ between 0 and 1

Comment: Is this supposed to be a path/line integral?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 the path is $g(t)=(t,t^2)$ between 0 and 1

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a [line integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) or in some texts, a path integral.

In general, if $C$ is a curve parameterized by $(x(t),y(t))$ for $t$ from $a$ to $b$, then

$$\displaystyle\int_{C}P(x,y)\,dx+Q(x,y)\,dy = \int_{a}^{b}\left[P(x(t),y(t))x'(t)+Q(x(t),y(t))y'(t)\right]\,dt$$

This can also be generalized to three or more variables.

Here we have $x(t) = t$, $y(t) = t^2$ from $t = 0$ to $1$, so the integral becomes:

$$\displaystyle\int_{C}(x+y)\,dx+1\,dy = \int_{0}^{1}\left[(t+t^2) \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 2t\right]\,dt$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i am not sure if $(x+y)dx+dy$ means $(x+y)dx +1dy$ or $(x+y)(dx+dy)=(x+y)dx +(x+y)dy$

Comment: For a moment, pretend $dx$ and $dy$ are real numbers. Does $(x+y)a+b$ mean $(x+y)a+1b$ or $(x+y)(a+b) = (x+y)a + (x+y)b$?

Comment: I know, but i was thinking that maybe is a cuestion of notation

Comment: Because i have other integral to solve that is $\int \frac{dx + dy}{x^2+y^2}$ over the path $g(t)=(cos(t),sin(t))$